# GetRawInputData not working for x64 build

Tags: c++, winapi, 64-bit, user32

GetRawInputData works fine with x86 build, but not with x64.

```
UINT32 dwSize = 40;
static BYTE lpb[40];
GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lparam, RID_INPUT, lpb, &dwSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
```

I'm using it to get mouse input. In x86 build I get proper values, but on x64 it returns 0 for lLastX and lLastY.

```
RAWINPUT* raw = (RAWINPUT*)lpb;

if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE)
{
  int xPosRelative = raw->data.mouse.lLastX;
  int yPosRelative = raw->data.mouse.lLastY;
  ...
```

I'm pretty much using the code from the Microsoft website, so I'm not sure where to go from this point. Google didn't help. Thanks!

Comment: Dude how can anyone help you with so little info?

Comment: Present your [mcve]. Spend at least as much time constructing your question, as you want to be taken constructing your free solution.

Comment: Sorry for the bad question, I've used the code from the example on Microsoft page, and didn't do anything to the code except changing the target build to x64; Since I need a x64 .dll.

Comment: You need to present a [mcve] IJM. This is not a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: You don't even tell us how you're building and executing the code, assuming you have a full program somewhere

Comment: Ok, sorry for that. I'll make sure to ask my questions with more details in the future.

Comment: @IJM Since this is a Q&A repo rather than a helpdesk, you should still edit this question into a complete form. Not just "in the future", but now! That's how you contribute back.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`dwSize` should be set to the size of the buffer. The buffer appears to be of different sizes on the two targets (which is to be expected as integer sizes vary, for example).

In the below example I pick 65,000 arbitrarily, but you'll need to work out the correct value for your application.

```
dwSize = 65000;
BYTE * lpb = new BYTE[dwSize];
GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lparam, RID_INPUT, lpb, &dwSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
```

Comment: Possibly true but should we not discourage questions like this until they are complete and resplendent in all necessary detail?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess you're a lot more optimistic than I am.

Comment: Thanks bro. In the example i found it was set to 40, I didn't change that. Setting dwSize to 65000 fixed the problem.

Comment: Sorry for my noob question, this is my firs question on StackOverflow ever, in general I find everything by Googling. I've updated my question to include dwSize. btw. I found other people with same problem, but no answers; So I thought that solution will be a bit more complicated.

Comment: Don't leave it at 65000 though. Find out what it _should_ be and use that.

Comment: Changing the dwSize did fix the problem, so this answer is correct. If I ever post another question, I'll make sure to do a much better job.

Comment: All right, now that I know that was the problem I'll resolve it. I had no idea what was wrong.

Comment: btw. You guys are super quick, expected to get an answer in like 3 days ;)

Comment: @IJM it could have been even quicker if you had shown more code initially as Lightness had suggested. I had to go out on a limb and guess the answer.

Comment: @IJM [Read the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getrawinputdata)! **[`RAWINPUT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-rawinput) mouse data is 46 bytes on x64, vs 38 bytes on x86**. For mouse/keyboard data, use `sizeof(RAWINPUT)` instead of a hard-coded number. HID data is variable-sized, so call `GetRawInputData()` with `pData` set to NULL to get the actual buffer size needed, then allocate the buffer and pass it to `GetRawInputData()` to fill in (you can optionally do the same for mouse/keyboard data).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for explaining that. I wish Microsoft could write stuff like that in their examples.